# Intempestive remote server/connection failed windows

Tags: macbook-pro, network, vpn, remote-disc

I have the following connection failed message on OSX 10.12.4. I'm used to access to a distant hard drive through a VPN (Cisco Anyconnect), but I removed that connection and the vpn software about two months ago. Everything was fine until yesterday where that message always showing up.

[image: Connection failed picture]

I've been in touch with Apple customer support, but so far, they were not able to help. There is no trace of the former server in network system preferences, finder, etc.

By monitoring the console, I noted that I have the following logs when the error windows show up :
[image: logs]

Regarding the logs, I checked in keychain if they were any references to the remote server, but I did not find anything. Would someone have an idea about how to solve the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. For future reference, can you please not use images to show what's in your log files. Instead, you can paste the text within your question, preferably using the `code sample` formatting. This just makes its easier for us to try and help you. Also, if you ever have a log that is too long to include within the question, then you can use [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com) to share the log by linking your question to it.

Comment: Also, I just find out that little snitch give me a reference regarding the remote server my mac tries to connect to, I hope it helps : "On 10 mai 2017, NetAuthSysAgent tried to establish a connection to SERVER.ca on port 445 (microsoft-ds). The request was allowed via connection alert."

Comment: Hi, I just did a clean install and re-installed some of my software (airmail, dropbox, steam, chrome, bitdefender), the message keeps showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, if anyone has it. Bitdefender tries to follow old shortcut that I have pointing toward folders on the remote server. I don't know why suddenly it tries to follow those folders, but if you need to solve this problem :

1. Open bitdefender
2. Click on "Antivirus for Mac" in the menue
3. Preference
4. Exclusions
5. Add the problematic folders, it should do the job